# How to use the "Curiously recurring template" pattern

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, linked-list, crtp

I'm not sure that there is allowed to ask questions like this. But I can't really understand the code which should be used in my program.

The situations is that I have to apply an earlier written class, which is design by some pattern and I have no right to change it. Unfortunately I don't know which patter it is, and neither how to use it.

(The story is about a linked list template.)

The code is something like this:

```
template<typename T> class LListNode {
public:
  LListNode();
  void setNext(T*);
  ...
  T* next() const;
};

template<typename T> inline void LListNode<T>::setNext(T* next) {
  static_cast<T*>(this)->m_next = next;
}
...
```

This was the node class, the next is the main list class:

```
template<typename T> class LList {
public:
  LList();

  bool isEmpty() const;
  ...
  T* head() const;
  ...
  void push(T*);
  ...
private:
  T* m_head;
  T* m_tail;
};
```

First, I tried to instantiate just the LList class with my own class as template class. But it didn't worked. Than I thought that maybe my own class (which will be stored in the List) should be inherited from the LListNode class. Thats seemed to be a good idea, but then there I got stuck.

**How can I define a class which is inherited from another class, which gets the currently defined class as template parameter?**

Just to make it clear:

```
class Foo : LListNode<Foo> {
private:
  Foo* m_next;
public:
  ...
```

At this point my compiler (gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.4-1ubuntu1~12.04) 4.6.4
) is crying:

```
In instantiation of 'void LListNode<T>::setPrev(T*) [with T = Foo]': 
required from LListNode<T>::LListNode() [with T = Foo]'
Foo.h:   required from here
LList.h: error: LListNode<Foo>' is an inaccessible base of 'Foo'
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: Thank you, now I know the name of my problem :)

Comment: Actually it's even the name of the solution...

Comment: And do you have any idea, why my compiler do not like this?

Comment: Did you try `class Foo : public LListNode<Foo> `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `public` :

```
class Foo : public LListNode<Foo> {
private:
  Foo* m_next;
public:
  ...
```

Comment: That's true! Thanks, but there are still some errors. I will now investigate them and than I will comment the news.

Comment: The last missing thing was: 
class Foo : public LListNode<Foo> {
friend class LListNode<Line>;
...}